# Por qué la ejecución del código no espera el resultado de un AlertDialog?

Tags: android, alertdialog

Describo cómo debe funcionar el código:
1.- En el Activity se llama a un AlertDialog, donde se pide al usuario 3 datos.
2.- Al AlertDialg solicita los 3 datos y los registra en las "preferences" del Activity.
3.- Al cerrar el AlertDialog, se debe buscar los datos que registró el AlertDialog en "preferences" y utilizarlos en cálculos.

Describo cómo está funcionando:
1.- En el Activity se llama a un AlertDialog, donde se pide al usuario 3 datos.
2.- En tanto el AlertDialog esta abierto y el usuario no ha terminado de registrar los 3 datos, en el Activity el código continua ejecutándose hasta buscar los datos en "preferences", y claro que no encuentra datos, tomando el valor por default de 0.
Al llegar al Toast la multiplicación mostrada es 0.
**3.- Cuando se cierra el AlerDialog, ya el proceso en el Activity se ha adelantado y terminado y no ejecuta ya ninguna acción con los valores que registró el AlertDialog por el usuario.**

Cómo hacer que el código espere hasta que el AlertDialog se cierre para continuar el proceso?

En el Activity, llamo al AlertDialog así:

```
AlertDialog dialogo = mostrarAlertAskDatosFaseFluidoGas();
            dialogo.show();
```

Y continua el Activity...

```
//Lee en Preferences los valores del array ordenBtns.
            SharedPreferences myPreferences = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(CalculoPSV_03.this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor myEditor = myPreferences.edit();

Double FactorK = Double.valueOf(myPreferences.getString("FaseFluidoGasFactorK", "0"));
Double FactorZ = Double.valueOf(myPreferences.getString("FaseFluidoGasFactorZ", "0"));
Double PesoM = Double.valueOf(myPreferences.getString("FaseFluidoGasM", "0"));

//Con la siguiente linea confirmo si aplica los valores que introdujo el usuario.
Double temp = FactorK * FactorZ;
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Multiplicacion: " + String.valueOf(temp), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

El AlertDialog lo creo así (la funcion esta en la misma Activity):

```
public AlertDialog mostrarAlertAskDatosFaseFluidoGas(){


    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

//...
//Se crean los Views del AlertDialog de forma programatica, en esta parte no hay problema.
//...


    // set title
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Datos Complementarios.");  

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Asigne valores de:")    //"Click yes to exit!"
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                   int numInicialIdsEditText = 220;
                    for (int i = 0; i < arrayValoresGas.length; i++) {
                        EditText testEditText = (EditText) scrollViewLayoutAlertDialog.findViewById(i + numInicialIdsEditText);
                        arrayValoresGas[i] = Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(testEditText.getText()));

                    }

                    SharedPreferences myPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(CalculoPSV_03.this);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor myEditor = myPreferences.edit();

                    //Guarda el valor de la variable global "GlobalRegistroCoordenadas".
                    myEditor.putString("FaseFluidoGasFactorK", String.valueOf(arrayValoresGas[0]));
                    myEditor.putString("FaseFluidoGasFactorZ", String.valueOf(arrayValoresGas[1]));
                    myEditor.putString("FaseFluidoGasM", String.valueOf(arrayValoresGas[2]));
                    myEditor.commit();


                }
            })


            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    dialog.cancel();


                }
            });

    // create alert dialog
    return alertDialogBuilder.create();



}
```

Gracias por su apoyo!!.
Saludos.

Comment: y porque no creas un metodo adicional que reciba la peticion de tu boton `setPositiveButton ` y que alli sea donde se ejecuten los calculos necesarios??, es más facil, porque si te das cuenta que muestres el alert no implica que el onCrete del activity se detenga

Comment: en pocas palabras, en el onCreate ejecuta el dialogo y delega los calculos a un metodo en la misma clase y que sea este el que continue el proceso